# warning: 'AVAudioSession' may not respond to '-setActive:fooError:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord fooError: &fooError];
//Activate the session
[audioSession setActive:YES fooError: &fooError];
```

The warning i receive is

warning: 'AVAudioSession' may not respond to '-setActive:fooError:'

Comment: That's wrong. You should accept my answer and start a new question. You have to keep the `&fooError`s and change fooError to error so it says `error: &fooError`.

Comment: This is just a mess. In the future you should ask another question if you have a new problem. Accept the answer of the person that gave you the right answer. Your title doesn't match your question anymore. Edit it. Stackoverflow is a great source for people that use google to find answers. By using stackoverflow like this, you mess it up.

Comment: Oh, changed it for you and the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning already tells you what the problem is: The `AVAudioSession` methods are called `-setCategory:error:` and `-setActive:error:`, not `-setCategory:fooError:` and `-setActive:fooError:`, respectively. You can change parameter names any way you want but not method names:

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &fooError];
//Activate the session
[audioSession setActive:YES error: &fooError];
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you your class, or a class that you're using has an instance variable called error in its header file. Try this:

```
 NSError *fooError = nil;
    oneAudioC = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&fooError];
    if (fooError)
        NSLog(@"%@",[fooError localizedDescription]);
```

**Edit:** Changed `if (error)` to `if (fooError)`

Comment: I guess you meant `if (fooError)`.